# Extracting patterns from data

Tags: r

I have a data frame with parking permit information for students at college. I have a lot of information but the pattern I am looking for is with regards to repeat customers over different academic years. Let me give you the basic idea of what I have and what I need.

```
Student.ID    Date.bought     Academic.year   Parking.Lot
001            Sept 7, 2008    Freshmen        West
001            Sept 2, 2009    Freshmen        West
001            Aug 10, 2010    Sophomore       East
002            Aug 12, 2009    Freshmen        North
002            Sept 4, 2011    Junior          North
```

I want to make flags for people who bought during freshmen year, freshmen + sophomore, freshmen + sophomore + senior, and basically other combinations. Would someone help me get a couple examples down, so I can create the other permutations on my own?

The desired end result would look something like this.

```
Student.ID    Freshmen     Fresh.Soph   Fresh.Junior
001           1            1            0
002           1            0            1
```

Basically end up with a true/false for each permutation I create.

Comment: What would the output from that sample data provide?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
df1 <- model.matrix(~Student.ID + Academic.year -1, data=df1)

df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

aggregate(. ~ Student.ID, data=df1,max)
```

Comment: I think I must not have worded my question correctly. I am looking for the combinations. So in the case of student 001, they bought a parking pass in their freshmen and sophomore year, so I want to make a column for "If you bought a parking permit for both your freshmen and sophomore year". In the case of student 001, they would have a True value there and for student 002 it would be false. In the column for "Did you buy a parking permit for your freshmen and junior year" the student 001 would have a false and student 002 would have a true value.